# Is a file in $_FILES the same as a file_get_contents when referring to an image?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

That being said, is **$uploaded_image** the 'same' variable using this:

```
$uploaded_image = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];
```

or this?

```
$uploaded_image = file_get_contents($some_image_url);
```

So that I can do another upload of the image to a third party server the same way independently of which code above? `uploadToOtherServer($uploaded_image)` (I'm sure this function works in the first case, what about the second?) Thank you for your help.

**PS: Considering both images are exactly the same**

Edit: going further, I'm uploading to S3. This works:

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'       => $bucket,
                'Key'          => $file_path,
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'ContentType'  => $content_type,
                'SourceFile'   => $_FILES['profile_picture']['tmp_name']
));
```

would this also work?

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'       => $bucket,
                'Key'          => $file_path,
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'ContentType'  => $content_type,
                'SourceFile'   => file_get_contents($image_url)
));
```

Comment: Nope, one is the filename the other is the file contents.

Comment: @Musa I've updatedmy question, would you care to take a look please? :)

Comment: That depends on the specific API, that being said I don't think it would work. The parameter name is `SourceFile` so looks its expecting a filename that it could read at its discretion and not the actual file data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']` and `$some_image_url` are both just paths pointing at a file. They are NOT the raw file data.

But if you had

```
$uploaded_image = file_get_contents($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);
```

then both would be equivalent - you'd have the binary data representing your file in the variable.

Comment: Pretty similar question, please take a look at it if you have some free time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812844/equivalent-filesimagetouploadtmp-name-when-i-use-file-get-contents-f

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the absolute file url ..

e.g. http://www.example.com/image.jpg so it reads as

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'       => $bucket,
                'Key'          => $file_path,
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'ContentType'  => $content_type,
                'SourceFile'   => 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg',
));
```

Following form login should get you going...

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Concept from the following form should get you going.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20130806T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 
    <input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your answer stating that passing a URL to the `SourceFile` is sufficient to satisfy the requirements of S3 API?

Comment: please answer @Mjh alpesh

Comment: this does not work stackoverflow.com/questions/34251296/cant-upload-image-to-s3-bucket-using-direct-url-of-image/34253844