# equivalent $_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"] when I use file_get_contents() function

Tags: php, image, file

I have a function like this:

```
fitImageSizeAndSave($_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) { ... }
```

That function works well. The first argument is `$_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"]`. Ok, it's good when an user upload an image from his local computer. But sometimes he enters a external link and I get that image like this:

```
$image = file_get_contents($_POST['external_link']);
```

How can I make `$image` like `$_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` for passing it to the function?

Comment: Can you share `fitImageSizeAndSave` function? Or are you just searching for something like `imagecreatefromjpeg` with `imagejpeg` ?

Comment: use `file_put_contents()` and then reference the temporary file that you've just put the data into

Comment: @Martin Sounds a great idea, may you please add an answer?

Comment: @mim. I just want to make `$_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` like `$image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use `file_put_contents()` and then reference the temporary file that you've just put the data into

---

> @Martin Sounds a great idea, may you please add an answer? –

---

`$_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` is simply a string to a file location on the server, it is not a resuorce in itself.

```
$filePathLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/some-temporary/file/storage";
$imageData = file_get_contents($_POST['external_link']);

if($imageData){
     file_put_contents($imageData, $filepathLocation);
}
else {
     $filepathLocation = $_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
}

fitImageSizeAndSave($filepathLocation, $target_file) { ... }
```

### The above, step by step:

- Set a temporary storage location; possibly based on [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) or something unique (database Id, if relevant) to limit different processes overwriting the same file path.
- get the contents of the `$_POST` file URL. save to a string variable.
- Check `if` variable is loaded ok; `else` use uploaded temporary file location ***THIS IS FOR ILLUSTRATION ONLY*** - You should have a more complete process for checking which data to use and the validity of said data already set up in your script.
- Send this variable to your custom function, knowning it is populated with one or the other of the possibilities above.

Answer (score -1):

The below is the PHP script to get image from url and save into your location machine or into own server

```
$imageurl ='http://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2015-08/mahesh-babu_630x450_81440064359.jpg';

$content = file_get_contents($imageurl);

if(file_put_contents('imagefolder/randomImageName.jpg', $content)){
     echo "File uploaded through URL";
}else{
    echo "File not uploaded...";
}
```